# UI JQUERY - эффект плавного отображения

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Что из этой библиотеки можете посоветовать для эффекта плавного добавления (отображения) контента на страницу

Comment: дурацкий вопрос

Answer (score 1):

можем посоветовать посмотреть варианты в официальной документации и выбрать на свой вкус: http://jqueryui.com/effect/#default